# What's the meaning of "auguring smoke" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Disappointment was arrival. Letters went out to the world, diaries, newspaper reports, warnings, laments, together with personal effects—eyeglasses, pen nibs, broken-backed Bibles—wrapped in soiled canvas. The stolen claim. Or the fortune squandered. (Lottie, dear, I have wasted our dream…) The trusting disposition. The false friend. The fog-shrouded wharf. The Spaniard Marquis, etc. The ring, the brooch, the opium den, etc.
>
> Narratives of disappointment flowed eastward, like an **auguring smoke**,
> or bumped back over rutted trails, as coffins bump or buckboards slow,
> to meet the stories of the desolations of the prairie life, rolled
> over those, flowed back to the Atlantic shore, where the raw line
> separating the North and South was beginning to fester.

Quoted from [here](https://alumni.berkeley.edu/california-magazine/january-february-2006-chinafornia/disappointment-0)

I found these meanings of "augur" as a verb: 1. To predict, especially from signs or omens; foretell. 2. To serve as an omen of; betoken: trends that augur change in society.

So, "auguring smoke" here is a metaphore, which imagines smoke as some signs and these signs are bad, am I right?

Comment: Yes, your explanation is right. Good job!

Comment: I agree with your explanation and with @Lambie

Comment: No final 'e' in 'metaphor'.

Comment: The phrase may refer obliquely to the idiom "[Where there's smoke there's fire](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/where-there-s-smoke-there-s-fire)," in the sense that the "smoke" of disappointment was a clue to the existence of trouble, and a prediction of disaster to come (the American Civil War).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your explanation, but the metaphor is more pointed than that. Smoke has been used as a means of augury, so *auguring smoke* makes reference to that. See

[Occult World *capnomancy*](https://occult-world.com/capnomancy-divinations/)

> Capnomancy, also known as Libanomancy, is a method of divination by interpreting the movement of smoke rising from a fire, principally sacrificial fires.

[Wikipedia *capnomancy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capnomancy)

> Capnomancy (otherwise known as libanomancy) signifies a method of divination using smoke. This is done by looking at the movements of the smoke after a fire has been made.